# VBA code works in debug mode but fails to run as macro

Tags: vba, excel

Hey i have a small problem that i can´t seam to solve... Im not the first to have this problem i found but none of the existing solutions worked on my code. so im stuck... The problem is that my code runs faster then what the functions can execute.

My code adds all worksheets that are of the same type together in a new sheet. And to indicate when how long every file is in the new sheet i want to change the interior of the last row to another color. My code can do that now but only in debug mode... and i don´t know how to "slow it down" so that i works whit my macro. Iv tried a delay function, DoEvent and adding a timer but none worked... Would really appreciate some tips on how to solve this or if there is a better way to do this. Thanks!

```
    Sub MergeSheets()
        Dim WorkSheetSource As Worksheet
        Dim WorkSheetDestination As Worksheet
        Dim RangeSource As Range
        Dim RangeDestination As Range
        Dim lngLastCol As Long
        Dim lngSourceLastRow As Long
        Dim lngDestinationLastRow As Long
        Dim SheetName As String
        Dim SkipSheets As String

        'Set references up-front
        Set WorkSheetDestination = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Import")
        lngDestinationLastRow = LastOccupiedRowNum(WorkSheetDestination) '<~ defined below (and in Toolbelt)!
        lngLastCol = LastOccupiedColNum(WorkSheetDestination) '<~ defined below (and in Toolbelt)!

        'Set the initial destination range
        Set RangeDestination = WorkSheetDestination.Cells(lngDestinationLastRow + 1, 1)
                                    ' (lngDestinationLastRow + 2) = what row to start adding on, 1 = start from column
        ' Skip this sheets          ' the 2 makes a blank row between sheeeeets
        SkipSheets = ("Import, Cover sheet, Control, Column description, Charts description")

        'Loop through all sheets
        For Each WorkSheetSource In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets ' Here i coud add a function where i can choose my Sheets?
            DoEvents
            'Make sure we skip the "Import" destination sheet!
            If InStr(1, SkipSheets & ",", WorkSheetSource.Name & ",", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then

                ' Skip all Charts sheets
                If InStr(WorkSheetSource.Name, "Status") Then

                    'Identify the last occupied row on this sheet
                    lngSourceLastRow = LastOccupiedRowNum(WorkSheetSource)

                    'Store the source data then copy it to the destination range
                    With WorkSheetSource
                        Set RangeSource = .Range(.Cells(3, 1), .Cells(lngSourceLastRow, lngLastCol)) ' 3 = what start row , 2 = how many columns
                            RangeSource.Copy Destination:=RangeDestination

                    End With

                    'Redefine the destination range now that new data has been added
                    LongDestinationLastRow = LastOccupiedRowNum(WorkSheetDestination)
                    Set RangeDestination = WorkSheetDestination.Cells(LongDestinationLastRow + 1, 1)
                    'LongDestinationLastRow.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 15
                End If

                ' Find last row and give it colour
                'Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Select
                'ActiveCell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 15
                ' don´t work... only in debugmode

            End If

' **** Here the code works in debug mode but not in macro!*****
            ' Find last row and give it colour
            Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Select
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 15

'*************************************************************

        Next WorkSheetSource
        MsgBox "Done"
    End Sub
```

Comment: Below Sub add "On Error GoTo ErrHandl" and above End Sub add "Exit Sub and in new Line ErrHandl: (new line) MsgBox(Err.Description) and if You want to continue Err.Clear and then below Resume Next" so that we will see what cause the error. Then we will try to do sth with it.

Comment: The thing is that i don´t get any errors, the code works fine. It´s just that i loads faster than what ( Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Select
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 15) change the interior color.

Comment: Looks like you've got unqualified references to a sheet, and the code is executing on whichever sheet you're on.  Did you verify that the color isn't applied to the sheets you're looping through?  "find last row and give it color" does not tell which sheet should be colored, so a sheet reference would be desired.

Comment: yes, you where right, i added "ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 15" and now i knows which sheet to indicate and it works as i wanted. Thanks! "@Cyril